# MOQ - Setup Mock Interface IDatabase for SqlDatabase

Tags: c#, testing, moq, xunit

In code I simply use:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    void Save();
}


public class SqlDatabase : IDatabase
{
    public void Save()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Saving data to Database");
    }
}
```

// Simple calling class...works fine!

`IDatabase database = new SqlDatabase();`

How do I do that in MOQ?

`Mock<IDatabase> mockDatabase = new Mock<SqlDatabase>();` does NOT work!!!

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type SqlDatabase to IDatabase

/////// UNIT TEST

```
    [Fact]
                public void SaveToDatabase()
                {
                    string comment = "Team, I know that times are tough! Product sales have been disappointing for the past three quarters. We have a competitive product, but we need to do a better job of selling it!";
        
                    Mock<IDatabase> mockDatabase = new Mock<IDatabase>();
    
// Not Required!
    // Mock<AnalyzerModel> mockAnalyzerModel = new Mock<AnalyzerModel>();
                // mockDatabase.Setup(x => x.Save(mockAnalyzerModel.Object));
        
                    var sut = new ToneAnalyzerEngine(mockDatabase.Object);
                    var v = sut.Analyze(comment, MockToneAnalyzerResultSadness());
        
                    mockDatabase.Verify(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<AnalyzerModel>()), Times.Once);
        
                    mockDatabase.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
                }

/////// Code Called

        internal bool Analyze(string comment, ToneAnalyzerResult toneAnalyzerResult)
        {
            bool isPositive = IsPositive(toneAnalyzerResult);

            AnalyzerModel analyzerModel = CreateAnalyzerModel(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), isPositive, comment);

            _database.Save(analyzerModel);
            return isPositive;
        }
```

Comment: It will be `Mock<IDatabase> mockDatabase = new Mock<IDatabase>();`. Why do you need Mock<SqlDatabase> ?

Comment: I'm trying to mockDatabase.Verify the Save method but always get 0 times! (instead of 1)

Comment: Please, add test code and, better, code being under test.

Comment: Try to setup your `Save` method. Add `mockDatabase.Setup(x => x.Save());` just after creation of mock.

Comment: added mockDatabase.Setup(x => x.Save(mockAnalyzerModel.Object)); but still get: Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times: x => x.Save(Mock<AnalyzerModel:1>.Object)

Comment: That's actually correct message. Invocation of `Save` happens but goes with another object. Your setup should look like: `mockDatabase.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<AnalyzerModel>());` - specifying that you expect calls to `Save` but don't what actual argument will be. And then you verify the call again via `mockDatabase.Verify(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<AnalyzerModel>()), Times.Once);`: again `It.IsAny<AnalyzerModel>()` means that you don't know what actual instance of `AnalyzerModel` will be passed to `Save`